Trouble Calling an Extension Function from an Interface in a Delegated Class in Kotlin
I have an interface ILoginExt with an extension function Login.logout(). This interface is implemented by the class LoginExt, and another class Login delegates ILoginExt to LoginExt. While I can call the logout extension function within the Login class, trying to call it from an instance of Login in the main function results in an "Unresolved reference: logout" error.
Please find the program below
fun main() {
      val login = Login()
      login.login()
      login.callLogOut()
            
      //Trying to call logout extension function. But received Unresolved reference 'logout' error.
      login.logout()
}
        
class Login: ILoginExt by LoginExt() {
      fun callLogOut() {
            logout() //Extension function can call from Login
      }
}
        
interface ILoginExt {
      fun login() {
            println("ILoginExt -> login() called")
      }

      fun Login.logout() {
            println("ILoginExt -> login() called")
      }
}
        
class LoginExt() : ILoginExt



This is possible.  You have to do it with
with(login) {
  login.logout()
}

The reason you have to do something this silly is that your design doesn't make much sense. logout() should not be an extension function, it should just be fun logout().  Right now, your design could have
with(login1) {
  login2.logout()
}

which doesn't make a lot of sense: why are there two different logins, what is being done by which one?

The code provided is meant to illustrate the problem statement. However, the actual project involves a different scenario. Thanks @Louis Wasserman
